# Facebook Graph API: How to tag a status update programmatically?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, status

How can I let a user tag their friends in their status post that they make through my app?

I don't see anything about this on the [Graph API Status Message Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about via status update, but via the [Facebook Graph API Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/), you can let users target their friends. The `to` argument takes an array of Facebook user IDs.